# How to turn on modem diagnostic mode on Samsung Galaxy Nexus

Tags: nexus, samsung

I am trying run [xgoldmon](https://github.com/2b-as/xgoldmon) utility with my old Samsung Galaxy Nexus. I follow instructions provided in README file.

> The Galaxy Nexus has to be rooted first to activate diag mode! Then:
>
> - In the adb shell, as root, enter:   echo MODEM > /sys/devices/tuna_otg/usb_sel
> - Connect to the first of the serial devices (e.g. /dev/ttyACM0) with   a terminal emulator and enter   AT+TRACE=1

I tryied with several factory images for Samsung Galaxy Nexus ("yakju" for Galaxy Nexus "maguro" (GSM/HSPA+)) from the [Google site](https://developers.google.com/android/images). I flashed Android 4.0.4 (IMM76I), rooted phone via [TWRP](https://twrp.me/samsung/samsunggalaxynexusgsm.html) installng [SuperSU](https://supersuroot.org/download/), connected to the phone via running `adb shell` and run

`echo MODEM > /sys/devices/tuna_otg/usb_sel`

Phone became disconnected and I did not see ttyACM* devices in /dev directory to enter AT commands. Also I could not connect with the adb tool.

When I did

`echo NONE > /sys/devices/tuna_otg/usb_sel`

I could connect to my phone with adb tool.

I tried the same things with  4.3 (JWR66Y) and got the same result.

There are several hardware versions of Samsung Galaxy Nexus, I suppose, but not sure, that I have a version that did not allow to work with modem diagnostic mode.

Can somebody say what I am doing wrong? And is there any solution to my problem?